# CentOS IPsec: We cannot identify ourselves with either end of this connection

Tags: linux, centos, ip, ipsec, openswan

I have problem with IPsec on centOS.
While adding a connection using

```
ipsec auto --add cx
```

It gives

```
multiple ip addresses, using  127.0.0.1 on venet0
```

On using

```
ipsec auto --up cx
```

I get We cannot identify ourselves with either end of this connection.

ip addr output

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: venet0: <BROADCAST,POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/void 
    inet 127.0.0.1/32 scope host venet0
    inet <here goes ip>/32 brd <here goes ip> scope global venet0:0
```

ipsec.conf

```
## general configuration parameters ##

config setup
    plutodebug=none
        plutostderrlog=/var/log/pluto.log
        protostack=netkey
        nat_traversal=yes
        virtual_private=%v4:10.0.0.0/8,%v4:192.168.0.0/16,%v4:172.16.0.0/12
        ## disable opportunistic encryption in Red Hat ##
        oe=off

## disable opportunistic encryption in Debian ##
## Note: this is a separate declaration statement ##
#include /etc/ipsec.d/examples/no_oe.conf

## connection definition in Red Hat ##
conn mazeed
    authby=secret
        auto=start
        ike=aes256-sha
        auth=esp
        ## phase 1 ##
        keyexchange=ike
        ## phase 2 ##
        #phase2=esp
        #phase2alg=aes256-sha
        compress=no
        pfs=yes
        type=tunnel
        left=<ip goes here from above>
        leftsubnet=192.168.30.10/24
        leftnexthop=%defaultroute
        right=<remote ip>
        rightsubnet=172.16.198.29/24
```

EDIT:
Ipsec Verify

```
Verifying installed system and configuration files

Version check and ipsec on-path                     [OK]
Libreswan U3.12/K(no kernel code presently loaded) on 2.6.32-46-pve
Checking for IPsec support in kernel                [FAILED]

 The ipsec service should be started before running 'ipsec verify'

Pluto ipsec.conf syntax                             [OK]
Hardware random device                              [N/A]
Checking rp_filter                                  [OK]
Checking that pluto is running                      [OK]
 Pluto listening for IKE on udp 500                 [FAILED]
 Pluto listening for IKE/NAT-T on udp 4500          [DISABLED]
 Pluto ipsec.secret syntax                          [OK]
Checking 'ip' command                               [OK]
Checking 'iptables' command                         [OK]
Checking 'prelink' command does not interfere with FIPSChecking for obsolete ipsec.conf options             [OK]
Opportunistic Encryption                            [DISABLED]

ipsec verify: encountered 3 errors - see 'man ipsec_verify' for help
```

However all ports are open in firewall

Comment: Gave up openswan and used strongswan instead which works without pain